# Web API HttpPost method always receives GET

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, http-get

I have a web api controller with a method

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate(HttpRequestMessage msg)
{
     //msg.Method is always GET
     // msg.Content is null 

}
```

I call it from my desktop application like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(){AllowAutoRedirect = false});
foreach (var header in headers)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
}
var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);
```

But in the web api method the property `msg.Method` is always GET and msg.Content is null

Is it sort of redirect or another intentional behavior that every request turns into GET?

I tried to change it to

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> C2dSend([FromBody]string request)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

but got 'BadRequest' after call.

The only thing that works is to replace string with dynamic:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> C2dSend([FromBody]dynamic request)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: If you post from Postman instead, does it appear as GET or POST?

Comment: What is the namespace of the `HttpPostAttribute`?

Comment: @mjwills it is from  the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only POST requests are routed to your action. You just looking at the wrong place - you are trying to bind body of your request to `HttpRequestMessage` instance. Obviously, you are passing something else here.

If you are looking for request details, use the [`Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.request?view=aspnetcore-2.2) property of controller. It is populated from contoller context which is passed to the controller during activation:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> C2dSend()
{
    // Request.Method is POST here
    return Ok();
}
```

But you don't need to use it to get request content. Let Asp.Net do this work for you - declare a model class which has the same properties as the serialized object which you are sending and model binder will do deserialization work for you:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> C2dSend(YourModel blah)
{
    // model will be populated automatically from request body
    return Ok();
}
```

Note: There is an easier way to send json requests. You can use PostAsJsonAsync extension from System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension